# TFS 2010 build Server Wix. Output only MSI

Tags: wix, tfsbuild

I've managed to get builds working on my build server, but now the issue I have is that the output in the output folder contains all output from all projects, rather than just the output from the wix project(s).

Any idea how to change this?

TIA

Comment: In TFS 2010 you can edit the build workflow (or possibly create a MSbuild file which you run at the end of the build) how familiar are you with XAML and WF?

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in the msi as a build output then you could create a step in your team build to copy your installer files to another location, the following build target, added to your build project should help.

This overrides the target [AfterDropBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337604%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
  <Target Name="AfterDropBuild">

    <PropertyGroup>
      <InstallerDir>$(DropLocation)\$(BuildNumber)\Installers</InstallerDir>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Message Importance="low" Text="InstallerDir=$(InstallerDir)" />
    <MakeDir Directories="$(InstallerDir)" Condition="!Exists('$(InstallerDir)')" />

    <CreateItem Include="$(BinariesRoot)\**\*.msi">
      <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="InstallationFiles"/>
    </CreateItem>

    <Copy SourceFiles="@(InstallationFiles)"
      DestinationFolder="$(InstallerDir)"/>

  </Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

I create different solution platforms { Application, Setup }  and set my .NET projects to build with application and my wix to build with setup.  Then I tell the build definition to build those two platforms in that order.  The result is that TFS archives the .NET code in an application folder that looks like the deployed machine and the MSI in the setup folder.

Only downside is when you add new projects you have to select the platform to build in configuration manager.  My developers don't seem annoyed by it though.